# Клирик, архиепископ, апостольский нунций... Кто из них каноник?

Tags: выбор-слов, титулы

**[Джованни делла Каза](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0,_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0)**

> С 1532 года благодаря покровительству Алессандро Фарнезе начал карьеру
>   **клирика**. Папа Павел III назначил его в 1544 году **архиепископом**
>   Беневенто и **апостольским нунцием** в Венеции.

У меня:

> **Академик Флоренции, каноник** Джованни делла Каза, по просьбе друга,
>   пишет наставления для племянника

<"Трактат мессира Джованни Делла Каза под названием "Синьор Галатео, или О хороших манерах">.

Что такое "академик Флоренции"?

---

Уточнение после невнятного ответа:

Клирик, архиепископ, апостольский нунций - это всё относится к Джованни Делла Каза. В моём же тексте Каза назван каноником, вот я и спрашиваю, как соотносятся эти титулы-звания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Джованни Делла Каза во Флоренции 11 февраля 1540 года, помимо выполнения своих обязанностей сборщика налогов,  был принят вместе с другими видными личностями во Флорентийскую академию, поэтому его и назвали здесь академиком.

Это крупный церковный деятель, он занимал высокие должности в рамках политики Контрреформации, которую проводил папа Павел III: он был папским нунцием (представителем с дипломатическими полномочиями ) в Венеции, смог снова ввести суд инквизиции на территории Венецианской республики и был очень активным посредником в переговорах между Венецией и папством, целью которых было убедить правителей морской республики выступить вместе с папой против императора Карла V.  Он лично вел судебные процессы против еретиков, в числе которых и против епископа Каподистрийского Пьера Паоло Верджерио. Как же он не был членом капитула (Совета клириков)? Конечно был, он им даже руководил.Он был даже государственным секретарём ( Секретарем Государства Святого Местопребывания).

Термин имеет греч. происхождение: κανονικός — название священнослужителя, внесенного в список, канон, т.е. каталог епархии. А это значит, что если священник **на службе** католической церкви получает жалование, он уже каноник, он в списке служителей, не священник со стороны.

Answer (score 1):

У вас заголовок совсем не соответствует вопросу в тексте.

> Что такое "академик Флоренции"?

Член Флорентийской академии наук. Кажется, она там даже не одна, но скорее всего речь идет об [этой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8).

> Клирик, архиепископ, апостольский нунций. Кто из них каноник?

Да может и никто, если они при этом не члены капитула.

Кано́ник (др.-греч. κανονικός, лат. canonicus, нем. Stiftsherr, Chorherr, англ. canon, фр. chanoine) в католической церкви — член кафедрального либо коллегиального капитула.

(Вики)