# Ещё со времён - ещё времён - времён ещё (с отсылкой к эпохе), - все варианты приемлемы?

Tags: грамотная-речь, порядок-слов

Дано:

> Сохранились и островки зелени времен ещё Древнего Рима.

Нужно что-нибудь править?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, всё в порядке, ничего править не надо. Все варианты приемлемы, смотря какой акцент хочет сделать автор. У него нормальный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо, Люсенька! С праздником! И нижайше прошу: загляните в проблемного "каноника" - https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/439792/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%9A%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA

Answer (score 1):

Из Нацкорпуса:

> Но, с другой стороны, подобные схемы очень неплохо известны **со времен еще** и Древнего Рима. [Сергей Есин. Маркиз Астольф де Кюстин. Почта духов, или Россия в 2007 году. Переложение на отечественный Сергея Есина (2008)]
>
> Может, мне бы не пришлось писать эти записки, если б мать через десять минут не встретила на путях своего курсанта **времен еще** гражданской и он не оказался комиссаром санпоезда. [Инна Пруссакова. «Я родилась в Ленинграде...» // «Звезда», 2003]
>
> О живописи говорили недолго, закончили рассматриванием альбома гитлеровских акварелей **времен еще** той войны, кто-то из фронтовиков подарил. [Виктор Некрасов. Саперлипопет (1983)]
>
> Я не так давно услыхал в Политехническом, а потом и прочел стихи Михаила Луконина «Коле Отраде» **времен еще** финской войны. [Константин Ваншенкин. Писательский клуб (1998)]